# In InstallCommand.php line 274: Parameter validation failed

Tags: validation, parameter, failed

I have problem installing magento 2.4.2
It shows me an error (In InstallCommand.php line 274:Parameter validation failed )
Help me
Thanks

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento/ \

> --db-host=localhost --db-name=pp_12 --db-user=root --db-password=00000000 
> --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=test@exampl.com 
> --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US 
> --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 
> --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=localhost 
> --elasticsearch-port=9200

Comment: can you create a database ??

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the following things.

1. Created the database, database user and database password.
2. Now Run the following commands.

> sudo php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="YOURURL"
> --db-host="localhost" --db-name="YOURDATABASENAME" --db-user="YOURDATABASEISERNAME" --db-password="YOURDATABASEPASS" --admin-firstname="test" --admin-lastname="test1" --admin-email="test@test.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"

Comment: I tried this in the hope of resolving the same issue as the OP, but Terminal responds "event not found".

Comment: In the command, you have to replace values respectively.